# Mouse control when using emacs in tmux

Tags: macos, emacs, mouse, tmux

I'm trying using Emacs and tmux in the Terminal.app, and having difficulty getting the mouse to work correctly.

If I use Emacs **outside** of tmux, then I **can** use the mouse to click on text to jump around the buffer.

However, if I am inside tmux, and I start editing a file in Emacs, then I can't click around. I have to do 
    M-x load-file ~/.emacs.d/init.el
.. to get it working.

Here is the content of my **init.el**

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line

(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://stable.gnu.org/packages/")
                             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line

;; magit
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'magit-status)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-g") 'magit-dispatch-popup)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c SPC") 'ace-jump-mode)

;; mouse
;; enable mouse reporting for terminal emulators
(unless window-system
  (xterm-mouse-mode 1)
  (global-set-key [mouse-4] (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (scroll-down 1)))
  (global-set-key [mouse-5] (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (scroll-up 1))))
```

..and my **tmux.conf**

```
set -g mouse on
bind X confirm-before kill-session
bind C-s set-window-option synchronize-panes
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"

set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'

bind -t emacs-copy C-WheelUpPane   halfpage-up
bind -t emacs-copy C-WheelDownPane halfpage-down


# plugins
set -g @plugin 'nhdaly/tmux-scroll-copy-mode'


run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

Versions

```
tmux version 2.1
emacsclient 24.5
macOS 10.11.4
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
(xterm-mouse-mode 1)
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252995/how-can-mouse-support-be-enabled-in-terminal-emacs/406519#406519